# Componentwise product of two matrices and the component wise product of their symmetric parts

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$, we have their Symmetric parts $\hat{A}=1/2(A+A^T)$ and $\hat{B}=1/2(B+B^T)$. Is there a simple relation between their componentwise product?

i.e. Are

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j}B_{i,j}~\text{and}~\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \hat{A}_{i,j}\hat{B}_{i,j}
\end{equation*}

related in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the notation $\langle A, B\rangle$ for the componentwise product of $A$ and $B$ (it's sometimes called the Frobenius inner product). You can check the following simple identities:
$$
\langle cA, B\rangle = c\langle A, B\rangle\\
\langle A, B+C\rangle = \langle A, B\rangle + \langle A, C\rangle\\
\langle A, B\rangle = \langle B, A\rangle\\
\langle A^T, B^T\rangle = \langle A, B\rangle
$$
The first three are just properties of inner products and the last one is somewhat special to the Frobenius product.

Then you have that
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \hat{A}, \hat{B}\rangle &= \frac14 \langle A+A^T, B+B^T\rangle\\
&= \frac14 \left(\langle A, B\rangle + \langle A, B^T\rangle + \langle A^T, B\rangle + \langle A^T, B^T\rangle\right)\\
&= \frac12\langle A, B\rangle + \frac12 \langle A, B^T\rangle
\end{align}
$$
So if you go back to the summations,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n{\hat{A}_{i,j}\hat{B}_{i,j}} = \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n{{A}_{i,j}{B}_{i,j}} + \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n{{A}_{i,j}{B}_{j,i}}.
$$